# How can I calculate the exact worst-case running time of a function given by a recurrence?

Tags: math, time-complexity, recurrence

I am trying to calculate the value of the running time at the worst case for a function whose worst-case runtime is given by this recurrence:

> T(0) = 0
>
> T(n) = n + T(n - 1) (if n > 0)

Does anyone have any advice how to do this? I don't see how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to try expanding out the recurrence to see if you spot a pattern:

- T(0) = 0
- T(1) = 1 + T(0) = 1 + 0
- T(2) = 2 + T(1) = 2 + 1 + 0
- T(3) = 3 + T(2) = 3 + 2 + 1 + 0

Based on this pattern, it looks like T(n) = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n. This is a famous summation worked out by Gauss, and it solves to n(n+1)/2. Therefore, we could conjecture that T(n) = n(n+1)/2.

You can formalize this by proving it by induction.  As a base case, T(0) = 0 = 0(0+1)/2, so everything checks out. For the inductive step, assume T(n) = n(n+1)/2. Then T(n+1) = (n+1) + T(n) = (n+1) + n(n+1)/2 = (n+1) (1 + n / 2) = (n+1)(n+2)/2 = ((n+1))((n+1) + 1) / 2, which checks out as well.

Therefore, your exact value is T(n) = n(n+1)/2.

Hope this helps!